# CSS Put image at top of page

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I need to have an image at the top-center of a web page in css. Now, Im just using the `background-image:` in css but this puts it at the middle of the page.

Here's my code:

```
body {
  background-image: url("theimageurlgoeshere"); //The image is 842 x 508
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also, Changing the `background-position:` seems to have no effect on the outcome of the site. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what browser are you targeting?

Comment: Not `background-attachment:fixed;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the arrangement of these values from `center top` to `top center`

```
background-position: top center;
```

Tested in Safari 4, Chrome, and FF 3.5

**The code I used in testing was:**

```
 body { background: url(./image.png) no-repeat top center; }
```

Comment: According to w3schools: The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Referencing http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties as an appropriate source for clarification. :-)

Comment: Your reference states (more accurately than w3schools): If at least one value is not a keyword, then the first value represents the horizontal position and the second represents the vertical position.

"not a keyword" indicates that both "top center" and "center top" are valid usages.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want it on a single line:

```
body {
  background: url('path') center top fixed no-repeat;
}
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 0):

If this dosen't work. Do margin:0 auto;